# Could not instantiate bean class: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to `@Autowired` a class which is a simple class, without Annotations, is just a class which has some calculation. However when I try to `@Autowired` that class, in my controller I get the following error:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LeituraController extends HemisphereController {

private static final String VIEW = "calculation/index";

@Autowired
private MyClass evapo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ModelAndView leituras() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(VIEW);
    Double valorMax = evapo.calculation();
    return view;
}}
```

Example of class:

```
public class MyClass {

public Double calculation(){
       //implementation
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.calculo.evaportranspiracao.MyClass net.pontoall.hemisphere.controller.LeituraController.evapo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.calculo.evaportranspiracao.MyClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 21 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.calculo.evaportranspiracao.MyClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:948)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:817)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
... 23 more
```

Anybody could help me? Thanks.

Comment: What does your constructor look like?

Comment: Need more information about the class and a bit more from the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: `public MyClass(
        ObjetoMonitorado objMonitorado, CalculoResource calculoResource) {
  this.objetoMonitorado = objMonitorado;
  this.calculoResource = calculoResource;
 }`

this way @DiegoBasch

Comment: Can you please share the whole context xml file

Answer (score 1):

The injected MyClass instance must be a Spring bean. Annotate it with `@Component` or another bean annotation, or declare it in the spring XML config file.

Comment: My XML: `<context:component-scan base-package="net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.calculo.MyClass" />`,
is it correct?

Comment: base-package, as its name indicates, expects a package name as value. Not a class name.

Comment: I should put: `net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.calculo` ??

Comment: You should put the base package under which all your annotated Spring beans are. Read [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-scanning-autodetection)

Comment: Yes, I know I corrected, but still not working.
`<context:component-scan base-package="net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.calculo" />`

Comment: @DaniloM. You say you know, but I don't think you do.  Check out the documentation that JB suggests.

Comment: Can you please share the whole context xml file