# Keep getting "No default constructor found" for controller

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I`m using Spring MVC with Jackson library for JSON(going to use the AngularJS then).
Here is the problem when I launch tomcat the "No default constructor found" error comes.
Here is the error log:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventController' defined in file [/home/greg/IdeaProjects/EventsOnMap/target/classes/home/map/events/rest/mvc/EventController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [home.map.events.rest.mvc.EventController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: home.map.events.rest.mvc.EventController.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [home.map.events.rest.mvc.EventController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: home.map.events.rest.mvc.EventController.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: home.map.events.rest.mvc.EventController.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 30 more

Sep 02, 2015 12:20:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /EventsOnMap threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: home.map.events.rest.mvc.EventController.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the controller(however other controllers work fine even they are almost identical except they are designed for different entities)

```
    @RequestMapping (value = "/event") @Controller
    public class EventController {
        @Autowired
        private EventService service;

        public EventController(EventService service) {
            this.service = service;
        }
        public EventController() { }

        @RequestMapping (value = "/event/{eventId}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<EventResource> getRoute(@PathVariable Long eventId) {
            Event event = service.getById(eventId);
            if (event != null) {
                EventResource res = new EventResourceAsm().toResource(event);
                return new ResponseEntity<EventResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<EventResource>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help I m facing this problem not a first day and no success reached.
Thank you

**UPDATE**
So you were right, I didn`t see that the error is different after adding the default constructor.

Thank you guys

Comment: *"Here is the new errorstack"* ... new error means new question. Please create a new one and accept one the the answers here, since they helped you with the non-argument constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have

```
@Autowired
private EventService service;
```

You do not need the constructor with parameter. You can remove it,

or add `@Autowired` to it and remove `@Autowired` from the property `service`

```
private EventService service;

@Autowired
public EventController(EventService service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should include no argument constructor in your class. Spring uses reflection to initialize beans so it will require no argument constructor.

```
public EventController() { }
```

**Note:** You do not need parameterized constructor either as you are using `@Autowired` on variable.

Comment: What error you are getting when you include default constructor?

Answer (score 3):

The class `EventController` is missing default constructor. It may be expected by Spring when initializing your bean. Please provide one like:

```
public EventController() { }
```

This might be helpful too:

[Could not instantiate bean class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766993/could-not-instantiate-bean-class-no-default-constructor-found-nested-exception)

[how to autowire a bean without default constructor](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/97753-how-to-autowire-a-bean-without-default-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any constructors in your class, a default non-arg one is provided for you by default, and Spring uses a non-arg constructor for bean initialization. Since you added a constructor with argument yourself (`public EventController(EventService service)`), the default one is no longer provided for you, so you need to add it manually.

```
public EventController() {
}
```

Or, just remove the one arg constructor if you don't need it and everything should work.

Comment: The exception should be different now, can you post the new one?